# Adding new entry to DataContext db Cause null reference

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-entities, datacontext

I'm a bit new to DataContext but it should still be simple.

I am developing a bidding site where there are many "Products" with each products many "Bids".
I have 2 tables (persisted in .NET to a DataContext Model):
BIDPRODUCT (with auctionID as primary key)
BIDENTRY (with auctionID as foreign key)
RELATIONSHIP: BIDPRODUCT --> BIDENTRY

I am trying to add 1 product with 1 linked bidentry to the db as such:
(`List<Products>` and `List<BidEntries>` is pre-populated)

```
        DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
        BidProduct p = Products.First();
        BidEntry b = Bids.Where(bi => bi.auctionId == p.auctionId).First();

        p.BidEntries.Add(b);

        db.BidProducts.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

When `p.BidEntries.Add(b)` is called I get a null reference on `BidEntries`!?
if I try `a = new` on `BidEntries` I still get a null reference.

What is this!?

Comment: try changing `Products.First();` to `Products.Include("BidEntries").First();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized `p.BidEntries` to a `List<BidEntries>`?

The error suggests that it isn't.

You need to ensure that after this point in your code:

```
 BidProduct p = Products.First();
```

`p.BidEntries` is not null - either assign a `new List<BidEntry>()` to it or ensure that each product has a non null `BidEntries` property.